# Hyperlinks missing from the QC (ALM) generated Email

Tags: html, hyperlink, hp-uft, alm, hp-quality-center

I am trying to send an email from HP ALM which is having some Hyperlinks, but those Hyperlinks are not visible.

I am tried searching on Internet and no luck.

Code:

```
 emails = "someone@somewhere.com"
 spath = "C:\Screenshot\ABC.png"
 spath1 = "C:\Report\ABC.pdf"
 Set tdc = createobject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
 tdc.InitConnectionEx "SERVERNAME"

 tdc.Login "UNAME", "PWD"
 tdc.Connect "DOMAIN", "PRJ"

 subject_str = "Automation Execution : " & Now

  Set fsoobj= CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

   Body_str = "<a href=" & spath & ">Screenshot path</a>" & vbcrlf & "<a href=" & chr(34) & spath1 & chr(34) & ">Report path</a>"
Wait 5
   tdc.SendMail emails, "Automation", subject_str, Body_str, "", "HTML"

Set fsoobj= nothing
Set Read_mail= nothing
tdc.Disconnect
tdc.Logout
tdc.ReleaseConnection
```

I tried both the ways using `" "`, no success. Please let me know if i am missing anything over here. I need that hyperlink to be displayed

Comment: have you tried sending plain text? Did it work?

Comment: Try `spath = "file:///C:\Screenshot\ABC.png"`

Comment: Any example of Network Tag or path